# SQL copy value from once column to another based on a condition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

There are 4 columns in my SQL table:

```
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
|Column1 |Column2   |Column3  |Column4 |Column5    |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| 1      |   abc    |   def   |        | 34654     | 
| 2      |   def    |   abc   |        | 798798    |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Goal is check if Column3 is in Column2, if it matches then fill Column4 with the respective value of Column1.

For example, "def" of Column3 matches "def" of Column2, so Column4 should be 2.

Desired output:

```
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
|Column1 |Column2   |Column3  |Column4 |Column5    |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| 1      |   abc    |   def   |   2    | 34654     | 
| 2      |   def    |   abc   |   1    | 798798    |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

I tried doing join on one of the tables like this:

```
SELECT a.Column1
, a.Column2
, a.Column3
, b.Column1 as Column4 FROM "table" a
LEFT JOIN "table" b on lower(a.Column3) = lower(b.Column2)
```

This creates a new Column4 when in my table Column4 already exists. I am doing UNION ALL of many tables and I need all my columns (32 in total) as the output.

How can I achieve this using SQL query?

Comment: look into "case when" statements

Comment: @Raj . . . I don't understand the question.  Just list all the columns that you do want.

Answer (score 0):

in a `SELECT`

```
 SELECT a.Column1
      , a.Column2
      , a.Column3
      , case when Column2 = Column3 
             then Column1 
             else Column4 -- keep same value
        end as Column4 
      , a.Column5
 FROM "table" a
```

in an `UPDATE`

```
 update "table"
 set Column4 = case when Column2 = Column3 
                    then Column1 
                    else Column4 -- keep same value
                end
```

Comment: Can we SELECT * to get all the columns in the table as output? Your SELECT statement only outputs Column1, Column2, Column3 and Column4.  What about Column5 in the output?

Comment: Just add `Column5` if you use `*` you will have 2 `Column4`.